# Rails + PostgreSQL + Nginx on Docker 構築する際にmacOS Chromeにて502 Bad Gatewayとなる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws, docker, nginx, postgresql

https://qiita.com/at-946/items/1e8acea19cc0b9f31b98#comment-48bbe03bc4d45b405cc6

ローカルで作成したrails日記アプリを、最終的には上記記事のようにRails + Nginx on Docker をEC2上に起き、RDS(postgresql)と接続させ、公開したいと考えています。

その前提準備として、
https://qiita.com/mkato7914/items/4938969fe1a90d23c7fb

こちらの記事で rails + postgresql on docker をまず構築し、MacOS chrome上でlocalhost3000でのアクセスとrailsアプリの動作は確認しました。その後、

=>https://qiita.com/na-o-ys/items/1a863419e1f6c3063ace

こちらの記事のパターンBにてNginx + rails + postgresql on docker　を構築したいと思い、RailsのDockerfileやNginx.conf その他パターンBにて必要なfileやディレクトリを追加し、記事中各file内のappとなっているところは自ローカルrailsアプリ名に変更するなど、前提準備第一段階のrails + postgresql on dockerの記事から修正や追加を行った段階です。

その時点のソースコードをgitにて共有させていただきます。

=>https://github.com/kouki-matsunaga/diary_app

この時点で、buildは上手くいったように思うのですが、localhost:8080(8000)にアクセスすると502 bad gateway　の表示がされ、おそらくどこかの定義ミスがあると思うのですが、ここで正直詰まってしまっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

前提準備2つ目の記事終了後、docker-compose buile　した際のターミナルでの表示です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

現在の私のソースコード(git参照)より、定義ミスやその他、修正箇所について助言いただけないでしょうか？

お忙しい中
大変申し訳ありませんが、ご返信いただけたら嬉しいです。

よろしくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[![コメントでいただいた修正を行って再度buildした結果画面です]

Comment: jellycsc here from stackoverflow.com. I'm happy to help. Looks like the puma webserver is not properly bind to a unix socket. Cloud you change `diary_app_root` in [this line](https://github.com/kouki-matsunaga/diary_app/blob/b36b3392e38513d85d5b9fe5c32db11ce30228b5/config/puma.rb#L40) to `app_root` and try starting the container again?

Comment: Puma.rb内のdiary_app_rootをapp_rootへ変更し、$ docker-compose up
して再度localhost8000(80)にアクセスしましたが、502 Bad Gateway　となってしまいます。

Comment: Is the previous error cleared in rails console? Are there any other errors shown in the terminal?

Comment: 以前のエラーはrailsコンソールにてクリアしていません。それをまずしなければならないのでしょうか？　そしてその方法はどうやって行うのでしょうか？

Comment: 5/23現在、質問中にあるリポジトリが閲覧可能状態に無いようです。